# How to create List of common element included if there are duplicates from two different List in Dart?

Tags: arrays, flutter, list, dart

I have Two List, and I hope to create a new list with elements in common and also with elements that have the same name

```
List<String> A=['cow','dog','cat','rat','dog'];
List<String> B=['dog','horse','rat','bird'];
```

I expect a result like this:

```
List<String> C=['dog','rat','dog'];
```

Comment: check [intersection](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-core/Set/intersection.html) method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your answer with below code:

```
List<String> C =  A.where((e) => B.contains(e)).toList();
```

Comment: or simply `A.where(B.contains).toList()` but actually it has bad performance for longer lists - it's better to use `Set.intersection()` method

Comment: @pskink, Yes you are right.   `Set` class method is more efficient in longer lists.